# Script fails to parse arithmetic comparison with double bracket

Tags: bash

I have this shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash
    
X=1200

if (( $X < 1000 )); then
    echo "true"

else
    echo "false"
fi
exit
```

Upon executing it I get these errors.

```
$ sh ./my-script.sh
./my-script.sh: 5: ./my-script.sh: cannot open 1000: No such file
./my-script.sh: 5: ./my-script.sh: 1200: not found
false
```

The parser fails to see the arithmetic brackets and tries to load file "1000" into variable $X. What am I doing wrong?

I am aware that you can use the alternative format `if [ "$X" -lt 1000 ]; then`, but I prefer the double bracket. Is this not how you do it in `/bin/bash`? A lot of places in the internet suggest that this is how you can do it.

- https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html
- https://devhints.io/bash
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/18668580/2126442

Comment: `sh` is not bash - see [DashAsBinSh](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh)

Comment: The "shebang" will become an ordinary comment if you run scripts like that. better set exec bit `chmod +x script` so you can run script with either relative path  `./script` or `/full/path/script`

Comment: Ah, so that's the difference. I was never sure when to use what methodology. Thanks; I'm learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`((...))` is not available in `sh` shell you are attempting to run your script with that in `sh ./my-script.sh`, use `bash ./my-script.sh` instead.